# firefox extensions, make notification box appear in all tabs

Tags: firefox-addon

Firefox has a native notification box system:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Alerts_and_Notifications#Using_notification_box

I'd like to use this system in a way that it appears in all opened tabs when it is supposed to appear. The code I have only warns you in the currently opened tab.

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation).QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem).rootTreeItem.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
var nb = mainWindow.gBrowser.getNotificationBox();
//...
outdatedNotification = nb.appendNotification("Your information outdated",
                                'outdate-warn',
                                'chrome://checksistem/skin/checksistem.png',
                                priority, buttons);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each tab has it's own notification box. You just need to loop over all the browsers and add the notification to each one. One thing you should know is the gBrowser.getNotificationBox can take a browser element:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml#337

If you don't pass a browser, the code returns the notification box for the active tab.

Try this:

```
  var browsers = mainWindow.gBrowser.browsers;
  for (var i=0; i<browsers.length; i++) {
    var nb = mainWindow.gBrowser.getNotificationBox(browsers[i]);
    outdatedNotification = nb.appendNotification("Your information outdated",
                                    'outdate-warn',
                                    'chrome://checksistem/skin/checksistem.png',
                                    priority, buttons);
  }
```